# Boost.Log vs. Boost.Log v2

Tags: c++, boost, boost-log, boost-logging

I am currently evaluating some log frameworks for unmanaged C++.

My question is: what is the difference between Boost.Log and Boost.Log v2?
Is the Api is different?
Is it safe to use Boost.Log v2 in a project or should I stick with Boost.Log 1.1?
When will be accepted into Boost? It may suffer major changes in the future?

Comment: You've seen this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3510473/experience-using-boost-log-logging-library ?

Comment: Yes, but i have read only the question :). I will post the response here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beware that the version "1.0" available is not being maintained. To receive updates you must use the bleeding edge (trunk) version which might become unstable. Take this into account if you are going to use this version in any serious projects. If you are not afraid to use bleeding edge versions or future breakage, then go for it. It's really nice to use as it is in its current state.