# Logging in a multiprocess application along with multithreading

Tags: c++, logging, boost, multiplatform

I am looking for a logging facility for a multiprocess application which also contains multiple threads with in each process.

My current application is only multi-threaded and uses ACE_Message_Queue for sending logging events to the logger thread (The actual Log message is shared between application threads and the logger thread through a global array).

My new application contains multiple processes with multiple threads with in each process. How can I achieve a decent logging functionality in this scenario? Also looking to get rid of ACE in favor of Boost. My new application is supposed to run on Linux,Mac and Windows.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Boost.Log](http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/index.html) (v2) is very easy to set-up and pretty comprehensive. It is not in the boost library yet but it will be soon. You can use it as a simple logger, or write filters and customize the logging process and output. I am using it for a project and very very happy with it. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3510473/390913).

Comment: My understanding, based on boost.devel ml discussions, is that Andrey has stopped supporting the library.

Comment: Don't think so. Do you have any links?

Comment: While boost.log is nice (I use it), it has been in a state of "being included soon" for a very long time.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [log4cplus](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/). It is an up-to date logging library allows using from multiple processes.

Answer (score 0):

I'v a blog to show my logging practice about this question: http://peihanw.blogspot.com/2012/08/my-answer-to-stackoverflows-question.html